# Error incompatible when use Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

[image: Error]

at image I don't know how to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Version of Fragment Class you are importing is it support Version or regular one

Answer (score 1):

`Fragment fragment` should instead be `FragmentOne fragment`. You're likely getting the error because `FragmentOne` is extending from a support Fragment instead of a regular Fragment.

In the future please post source code instead of a screenshot.